# Include php file in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Use jquery to add the drop down. The option value is from mysql database. It is included as `getItems.php`. Then, submit the selected value to mysql. It occurs the SyntaxError. It seems the php syntax is invalid in jquery. The included part cannot be shown on one row.

jquery:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
  $('#add').click(function(){
    var item = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item</label><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" name="item"><?php include 'getItems.php'; ?></select></div></div>';
    // error

    $('#addItem').append(item);
  });
});
</script>
```

php:

```
$query = "SELECT itemName FROM Item";
$results = mysql_query($query);
if (!$results) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  echo '<option>'.$row["itemName"].'</option>';
}
```

error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

console:

```
  var item = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item</label><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" name="item"> <option>Item1</option><option>Item2</option><option>Item3</option>
 </select></div></div>';
```

Last edit: change the `var item = $('')` to `var item = ''`. But it still has the same error.

Comment: Why $ after var item = ?

Comment: Tried this ? : `var item = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item</label><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" name="item"><?php include 'getItems.php'; ?></select></div></div>';`

Comment: You're breaking a new line after the last `</option>`

Comment: @BikashPaul I have tried var item = ' ';. But it still has the same error. It break a new line after the last </option>

Comment: have you established the mysql connection before using

Comment: @NathanP.   Yes, there is a new line. But I don't know why it occurs.

Comment: @BadshahSahib  Yes, mysql connectted.

Comment: @Vikrant   I have tried that. It has the same error.

Comment: then why dont  you use ajax instead of this method.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT itemName FROM Item";
$results = mysql_query($query);
if (!$results) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$options="";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  $options .= '<option>'.$row["itemName"].'</option>';
}
`

Comment: I don't know ajax... Is there any function can use?

Comment: don't use `mysql` use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead

Comment: okay i am sharing a method that you can use to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP: getresult.php

```
$query = "SELECT itemName FROM Item"; $results = mysql_query($query);
         if (!$results) 
        { 
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
         } 
        $options=""; 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
        $options .= '<option>'.$row["itemName"].'</option>';
         }
    echo  $options;
```

JQuery:

```
`<?php include('getresult.php'); ?>
<script>
 $(function() {
  $('#add').click(function(){
    var item = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item</label><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" name="item"><?php echo $options; ?></select></div></div>';
    // error

    $('#addItem').html(item);
  });
});
</script>`
```

OR
you can use ajax like this

```
<script>
$.ajax({
url:"getresult.php",
data:{},
type:"POST",
success:function(res){
$('#addItem').html(res);
}
});
</script>
```

Or you can simply use

```
<script>
 $('#addItem').load("getresult.php");
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the solution for JQuery. It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative to do your requirement,

```
 var item = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item</label><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" name="item"></select></div></div>';
 // first append all html to addItem, so content will be added to DOM.
 $('#addItem').append(item);
 // once html is loaded inside DOM, then load contents of getItems.php inside select as inner html. 
 setTimeout(function() {
   $("select[name='item']").load('getItems.php');
 }, 1000);
```

Please check [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) everything over here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try.

```
<script>
     $(function() {
      $('#add').click(function(){

        var items = <?php include 'getItems.php'; ?>;
        var item = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item</label><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" name="item">'+items+'</select></div></div>';
        // error

        $('#addItem').append(item);
      });
    });
    </script>
```